# Programmer's Notepad not Capturing Make Output?

Tags: compiler-construction, programmers-notepad

I've been using Programmer's notepad for a while now, I find it to be an amazingly simple tool and I prefer to use it on projects where I know I don't need most of the standard IDE overhead. However, I've recently run into this problem when running the program on Windows Vista.

I find that when running the built in "make" command, the output from make.exe isn't captured in the window like its supposed to be. The error code is being caught, but the output is always completely blank, regardless of what the program is actually outputting. (Running the program from the command line shows the output just fine, as does running it without using PN's "Capture Output" option.) Anyone know what the cause of this might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my partial solution to this problem was to switch compilers. Apparently, Programmer's Notepad doesn't like the output from DJGPP on Windows Vista, probably because DJGPP isn't a full port and has all sorts of other issues anyway. The solution is to just use a different compiler. We're now using MinGW for this project, and that solved most of our problems once we got the linker issues sorted out.

Still, if anyone has a way to make DJGPP work with PN (I know there are still some projects that rely on it) it would be helpful to know.